# Linux TCP tuning to overcome choking uplink

Tags: linux, tcp, traffic-shaping

A linux computer is on a network link which exhibits the following behaviour:

- good download speeds
- upload/uplink starts well but after a few seconds drops to close to nothing. The Send-Q and Recv-Q numbers for those sockets are high, in hundreds or thousands, high retransmit count.
- using interactive reverse shell (think remote console) if I execute a command that has small output (e.g. "whoami") or ls of a small file count directory it remains stable-ish. If I generate a large output (even ps xauww), the connection stutters and may never recover
- ethernet interface reports no packet loss

I cannot influence anything that goes beyond this one computer. I am looking for ideas on how can I tune TCP stack on Linux to overcome this behaviour.
Update:

```
net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control = westwood
net.core.default_qdisc = fq_codel
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1000 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether zz:yy:yy:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
Linux pc2 5.15.0-84-generic #93~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 6 16:15:40 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Example connection:

```
ESTAB    0         140304         192.168.X.X:34554       YY.YYYY.YY.YYYY:443
         westwood wscale:9,7 rto:1200 backoff:2 rtt:98.553/3.011 ato:40 mss:948 pmtu:1000 rcvmss:948 advmss:948 cwnd:1 ssthresh:2 bytes_sent:668936 bytes_retrans:247428 bytes_acked:418665 bytes_received:8329 segs_out:719 segs_in:443 data_segs_out:708 data_segs_in:10 send 79000bps lastsnd:816 lastrcv:80600 lastack:1964 pacing_rate 184680bps delivery_rate 73992bps delivered:445 busy:80800ms unacked:3 retrans:1/261 lost:3 reordering:10 reord_seen:3 rcv_space:9480 rcv_ssthresh:64588 notsent:137460 minrtt:93
```

- The MTU=1000 was my attempt to indirectly change the packet size to stave off some future incorrect fragmentation. Neither 1500 nor 1000 values make a difference
- the tcp westwood was my attempt at a different algorithm. Before that I tried cubic with no effect

Comment: What is the pysical link? Is it Wi-Fi? Can you please edit your question with the result of `ip l`, `sysctl net.core.default_qdisc` and `sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control`? (the expected result is small so it shouldn't disconnect you)

Comment: `upload/uplink starts well but after a few seconds drops to close to nothing.` Asymmetrical performance such as this is not uncommon in low-cost consumer services.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a modern Linux installation (<10 yrs old) then the most likely cause *based on the information you have provided* is either your perception of the issue or a fault on the network. Linux is already tuning the TCP/IP stack.

Perception: When a TCP host starts sending data, it starts off slowish and ramps up the speed very quickly (specifically by controlling the congestion window). When something along the path to the target says it can't cope with more data (i.e. it is receiving data faster than it is forwarding the data and its buffers are filling up) it will tell the originating host to back off. The result is that you should expect to see a damped oscillation in your network throughput.

But it is possible that something else is going wrong (and most likely elsewhere than the originating host). Have you tried different hosts attached to the same network port connecting along the same path? Are you able to get metrics on bandiwdth / throughput / congestion from at least the first network hop?

Comment: Unfortunately this one host is all I have. The setup is a PC connected to a SOHO router to a "modem" which I suspect is ADSL.